# How to save the generated XML file in a directory passing him in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

Personally I'm with a doubt saving my XML in sql server. I am using FOR XML PATH to generate the xml from a table in my database. The sql server shows me on the screen the XML generated but not saved to file it (well, I guess not lol). How do I save it by passing a directory?

I have the following query to generate XML:

select TableName, 
operation, 
UserName, 
DataAcesso, 
CamposTabela, 
ValoresCampos, 
CamposPKs, 
ValoresCamposPKs 
FROM TabelaLog 
FOR XML PATH ('Log')

anyone know how to save to file? 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [BCP utiity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

```
bcp "select TableName, operation, UserName, DataAcesso, CamposTabela, ValoresCampos, CamposPKs, ValoresCamposPKs FROM TabelaLog FOR XML PATH ('Log')" queryout "D:\MyTable.csv" -c -t , -S SERVERNAME -T
```

However, the headers must be passed explicitly, if you want them. You can use a UNION ALL for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post. Has some good instructions on exporting info from a query\table to file

[How do I send a database query to a text file?](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-send-a-database-query-to-a-text-file.html)

Alternatively you could use SQL Server Integration services (SSIS) and setup a scheduled job to export the information periodically. That would be my option. Another alternative would be to pull it into your application and then save\export it from server side code rather than letting the database do it for you.